# jCarousel Infinite Loop - no width or height set

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I've setup jcarousel to dynamically load elements as they disappear and then have them reappear

now it's given me an error saying: "No width/height set for items."

I've tried the hack described here: http://old.nabble.com/jCarousel:-No-width-height-set-for-items.-td13913308s27240.html

and it caused firefox to crash (probably because it's looping constantly)

any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a link to the site so I can see the code?

Comment: @TALLBOY - I put a working example of the error that Chris might be seeing here http://jsfiddle.net/xv7yN/.  This example only throws an error in IE6 (surprise surprise) - I blew away the code that was causing an error in all browsers - but I will try and post a full browser example soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an explicit height on the .jcarousel-clip container

Comment: That's `.jcarousel-item`for the Drupal module. Assign any random width; it will be overwritten automatically…

Answer (score 6):

```
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel(
{
    auto : 2,
    scroll : 1,
    wrap : 'last',
    initCallback : mycarousel_initCallback,
    itemFallbackDimension: 300
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So ignore my comment response to @TALLBOY.  I was able to fix this issue by specifying a width for div.carousel-container which is an element that is added by the code when the carousel is initialized.

I stumbled across this during my searches:

http://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/issuesearch?state=open&q=width#issue/22

Answer (score 1):

Guys this should work

```
.jcarousel-list li { height:??px; width: ??px; }
```

When you put your height and width in, in your css file it should appear.