# JCarousel No width / height set for items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

OK, losing my mind somewhat. I need some help with JCarousel on a site I am working on for a customer. For some reason, I have been stuck for hours now on the above issue. No matter what I try, I still have the issue (although the Carousel works OK on the page once loaded, go figure!)

I have tried [this](http://drayblog.gotdns.com/index.php/2011/03/31/jcarousel-no-width-height-set-for-items/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784925/no-width-height-set-for-items-this-will-cause-an-infinite-loop-aborting) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417524/jcarousel-infinite-loop-no-width-or-height-set) among other suggestions but no luck, the error still appears.

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="Block BlockContent">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/content/PromoBannerCarousel/pbjcarousel.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/PromoBannerCarousel/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>

    <div class="jcarousel-skin-promobanner">
        <div class="jcarousel-container jcarousel-container-horizontal" style="position: relative; display: block;">
            <div class="jcarousel-clip jcarousel-clip-horizontal" style="position: relative;">
                <ul id="promobannercarousel" class="jcarousel-list jcarousel-list-horizontal" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; top: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; top: -500px; left: 0px; height: 90px; align: center;">
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://itoutlet.com.au/free-shipping-promotion-sep-2013/">
                           <img src="/content/PromoBannerCarousel/images/augfreedeliveryselprodmini.jpg" title="Free shipping on selected products throughout our store, available from Sep 11 to Sep 30 or while stocks last"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="https://itoutlet.com.au/acer-promotions/">
                           <img src="/content/PromoBannerCarousel/images/acercashbackmini.jpg" title="Acer fantastic Laptop & All In One + Shipping cash back offers! Limited stocks, do not miss out!"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://itoutlet.com.au/hp-promotions/">
                           <img src="/content/PromoBannerCarousel/images/hpaugoffersmini.jpg" title="HP fantastic Laptop + Shipping offers! Limited stocks, do not miss out!"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://itoutlet.com.au/wd-promotions/">
                           <img src="/content/PromoBannerCarousel/images/wdpetrolpromotmini.jpg" title="WD Personal Cloud + Petrol Voucher + Shipping Promotion"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>  
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://itoutlet.com.au/lenovo-promotions/">
                           <img src="/content/PromoBannerCarousel/images/lenovoaugoffersmini.jpg" title="Great ThinkPad + Shipping offers from Lenovo. Limited stocks, do not miss out!"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://itoutlet.com.au/samsung-tablets/">
                            <img src="/content/PromoBannerCarousel/images/galaxyfreeshipmini.jpg" title="Thin, light, stylish, Samsung Galaxy + Shipping offers. Limited stocks, do not miss out!"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="/content/PromoBannerCarousel/images/5shippingmini.jpg" title="$5 shipping anywhere in Australia on selected accessories. Look out for the $5 Shipping tag!"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="jcarousel-prev jcarousel-prev-horizontal" style="display: block;"></div>
            <div class="jcarousel-next jcarousel-next-horizontal" style="display: block;"></div>
        </div>

    </div>    

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">   
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#promobannercarousel').jcarousel({
        auto: 4,
        scroll: 1,
        wrap: 'circular',
        animation: 500,
        iniFallbackDimension: 90,
        itemLoadCallback: {
            onBeforeAnimation: mycarousel_fadeOut,
            onAfterAnimation: mycarousel_fadeIn
        }
    });
    function mycarousel_fadeOut(carousel) {
        var JCcontainerID = carousel.clip.context.id;
        $('#' + JCcontainerID).fadeOut();
    }

    function mycarousel_fadeIn(carousel) {
        var JCcontainerID = carousel.clip.context.id;
        $('#' + JCcontainerID).fadeIn();
    }
});
</script>
```

and the CSS can be found [here](https://itoutlet.com.au/content/PromoBannerCarousel/pbjcarousel.css).

Here's a [link](http://itoutlet.com.au/promotions/) to a page showing the issue. The Carousel is the Promotions Banner at the top of the page. I see the issue using Chrome (latest release).

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

PS:I do not see the error in FireFox (latest release) so not sure why it would be an error in Chrome but not FF...

PSS: You will also see when the page loads the first image flickers a few time before it settles. I have never had this happen with JCarousel and I have tried a few ways to solve this too... if you have any suggestions on this I would appreciate it very much also!!

Thanks in advance for any help!
M

Comment: on jcarousel options there is iniFallbackDimension, should this be itemFallbackDimension?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes it was a typo on my side, but it was not working at my end with the code correct. I have moved over to Nivo Slider instead.